# How to fetch only numeric value in a string using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to fetch one item in the string,

the main string is : This is an inactive AAA product. It will be replaced by replacement AAAA/BBBB number ABX16059636/903213712 during quoting

I would like fetch only "903213712", is there any way to achieve this one using Regex ?

Tried with below regex, it gives 16059636/903213712 == > I'm expecting only 903213712 after slash.

```
var string = "This is an inactive AAA product. It will be replaced by replacement AAAA/BBBB number ABX16059636/903213712 during quoting"

var result = string.match(/\d+/g)

//var resVal = result.toString().split("/");

alert(result);
```

Comment: try: `string.match(/\d+$/)`

Answer (score 8):

you are almost done `\/` is missing => `/\/(\d+)/g`

**Explanation**

1. `\/` match the `/`
2. `\d+`  matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) .for more info see the demo regex

[**Demo regex**](https://regex101.com/r/ijL7S2/1/)

```js
var string = "This is an inactive AAA product. It will be replaced by replacement AAAA/BBBB number ABX16059636/903213712 during quoting"
var result =/\/(\d+)/g.exec(string)
console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, actualy I have lot strings I need to fetch the values. I'm getting result like below /1619854998,/254738814,/272071779,1619854998,254738814,272071779.... im just alerting  alert(result.toString());

Comment: @Rajasekhar ok..What you have expect from my answer?.can you explain more clear

Comment: console.log(result[1]); is fine for fine, here my requriement is I need iterate all strings and pushed to one array and I need to alrert all array values. alert(result.toString()); >> for this one Im getting "/903213712,903213712". Insted of result[1], can I use result.toString() ?

Comment: Yes ..you could do with that.its just a out method.Not necessary for `console.log` .I was just print the second value That's all